# NextJS page does not re-hydrate when refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I am building a NextJS blogging site which uses `@expo/next-adapter` . This site has two pages. One is the `user` page and the other one is `post` page.  The user page has `getServerSideProps` implemented to fetch data from Firebase. There is `next/link`'s `<Link />` implemented on the `post` page which points to `/user/[uid]`.

Now the problem is if I navigate to `user` from `post` using the `<Link />` Everything works ok but if I refresh the page the page becomes unresponsive and all the styling related client side JS does not run.

PS : SSR is not implemented on the `post` page. Please forgive me if this is a rookie mistake because I am one.

PS #2 : This project is hosted on Firebase and uses a cloud function to handle SSR. The above problem does not show up if I run the production build locally using `next build && next start`

Thank you in advance...

Edit #1 :
This error shows up on the browser console when I either try to manually go to `/user/[uid]` or refresh the page after navigating back from `post`

```
main-590e886005382c6f8e8a.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at DqTX.t.default (main-590e886005382c6f8e8a.js:1)
at Object.IKlv (main-590e886005382c6f8e8a.js:1)
at l (webpack-288ceb4b356766e18474.js:1)
at Object.BMP1 (main-590e886005382c6f8e8a.js:1)
at l (webpack-288ceb4b356766e18474.js:1)
at t (webpack-288ceb4b356766e18474.js:1)
at Array.r [as push] (webpack-288ceb4b356766e18474.js:1)
at 0c947092cfe8a35964e0670062fe3410218106ea.62154c5756c292e8972d.js:1
```

Edit #2: **Code for the function** `[user].js`

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

if(admin.apps.length == 0){
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        storageBucket: '*************.appspot.com',
    });
}
try {
const fireStore = admin.firestore();
const userDataRef = await fireStore.collection('users').where('uid', '==', `${context.query.user}`).get();
const postDataRef = await fireStore.collection('posts').where('uid', '==', `${context.query.user}`).get();
let userData;
let postData = [];
if(!userDataRef.empty){
    if(userDataRef.docs[0].exists){
        userData = userDataRef.docs[0].data()
    }
    if(!postDataRef.empty){
        for(let post of postDataRef.docs){
            const thumbImage = await admin.storage().bucket().file(`postData/${post.id}/${post.data().thumb}`).publicUrl();
            deckData.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({...post.data(), id: post.id, thumb: thumbImage})));
        }
    }
}
return {
  props: {user: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData)), posts: [...postData]}, // will be passed to the page component as props
}
   } catch(e) {
  return {
       props: {user: 'error', posts: []},
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Is hard to tell what is wrong without the code of your function

Comment: @JanHernandez Can you please check now?

Comment: When you navigate to user from post using the <Link />, are you passing some arguments?